# How to deal with javascript async await coding pattern in Java?

Tags: java

I want to rewrite some JavaScript component in Java. It actively uses `async await` and `Promise` keywords.

My question is how to deal with `async` functions in Java? Should I return `CompletableFuture`? Can I make some wrappers for that purpose to simply rewrite code like this:

```
async cbToPromise(cb) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        cb((resp) => {
            resolve(resp);
        })
    });
}

async profileScope(msg, cb) {
    const start = process.hrtime();
    await cb();
    this.log(msg, `took ${Math.round(this.getPerfTime(start))}ms`);
}

const loaded = this.cbToPromise(loadEventFired);
await this.profileScope('Wait for load', async () => {
                    await loaded;
                });
```

Comment: io.netty.util.concurrent;